# Getting this error "Argument 2 cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable string ' to 'string '"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

Here is the line of code

```
result = await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, model.Where(x => x.IsSelected)
            .Select(y => y.RoleName));
```

Comment: AddToRoleAsync expects a string, not a sequence of strings. Add Single() or First() or something similar to your Linq expression.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `FirstOrDefault` to get only one value of the collection

Example:

```
result = await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, model.Select(y => y.RoleName)
                                                     .FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsSelected)??"");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var role= model.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsSelected);
if(role ==null) ... error;
           
result = await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role.RoleName);
```

or maybe

```
var roleName= model.Where(x => x.IsSelected).Select(i=> new {Name=i.RoleName}).FirstOrDefault();
result = await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, roleName.Name);
```

Comment: Solved Thank You.

Comment: parameters accepting list but i was passing string. I placed the solution below

Answer (score -1):

```
Solved by replacing this code
```

var roleName=model.Where(x => x.IsSelected).Select(y => y.RoleName).ToList();

```
        if(roleName!=null)
        {
            foreach (var roleN in roleName)
            {
                result = await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, roleN);
            }
        }
```